# Print a word in array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays

```
$itemData['show_min_driver_age'] = $itemData['min_driver_age'] > 0 ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

I would like to print "Years" after the age of the Driver

For now i Have Minimum Driver Age : 18

How can i do that ?

Here is the complete code

```
public function getDetails($paramBasicDetails = FALSE)
{
    $itemData = $this->getDataFromDatabaseById($this->elementId);

    if(!is_null($itemData))
    {
        $image1_Folder = $itemData['demo_image_1'] == 1 ? $GLOBALS['NRS_DEMO_GALLERY_URL'] : $GLOBALS['NRS_GALLERY_URL'];
        $image2_Folder = $itemData['demo_image_2'] == 1 ? $GLOBALS['NRS_DEMO_GALLERY_URL'] : $GLOBALS['NRS_GALLERY_URL'];
        $image3_Folder = $itemData['demo_image_3'] == 1 ? $GLOBALS['NRS_DEMO_GALLERY_URL'] : $GLOBALS['NRS_GALLERY_URL'];

        // Extend $item with additional details
        $itemData['item_description_page_url'] = $itemData['item_description_page_id'] != 0 ? get_permalink($itemData['item_description_page_id']) : "";
        $itemData['manufacturer_title'] = $this->getManufacturerTitle($itemData['manufacturer_id']);
        $itemData['body_type_title'] = $this->getBodyTypeTitle($itemData['body_type_id']);
        $itemData['fuel_type_title'] = $this->getFuelTypeTitle($itemData['fuel_type_id']);
        $itemData['transmission_type_title'] = $this->getTransmissionTypeTitle($itemData['transmission_type_id']);

        $itemData['mini_thumb_url'] = $itemData['item_image_1'] != "" ? $image1_Folder."mini_thumb_".$itemData['item_image_1'] : "";
        $itemData['thumb_url'] = $itemData['item_image_1'] != "" ? $image1_Folder."thumb_".$itemData['item_image_1'] : "";
        $itemData['big_thumb_url'] = $itemData['item_image_1'] != "" ? $image1_Folder."big_thumb_".$itemData['item_image_1'] : "";
        $itemData['image_url'] = $itemData['item_image_1'] != "" ? $image1_Folder.$itemData['item_image_1'] : "";

        $itemData['mini_thumb_2_url'] = $itemData['item_image_2'] != "" ? $image2_Folder."mini_thumb_".$itemData['item_image_2'] : "";
        $itemData['thumb_2_url'] = $itemData['item_image_2'] != "" ? $image2_Folder."thumb_".$itemData['item_image_2'] : "";
        $itemData['big_thumb_2_url'] = $itemData['item_image_2'] != "" ? $image2_Folder."big_thumb_".$itemData['item_image_2'] : "";
        $itemData['image_2_url'] = $itemData['item_image_2'] != "" ? $image2_Folder.$itemData['item_image_2'] : "";

        $itemData['mini_thumb_3_url'] = $itemData['item_image_3'] != "" ? $image3_Folder."mini_thumb_".$itemData['item_image_3'] : "";
        $itemData['thumb_3_url'] = $itemData['item_image_3'] != "" ? $image3_Folder."thumb_".$itemData['item_image_3'] : "";
        $itemData['big_thumb_3_url'] = $itemData['item_image_3'] != "" ? $image3_Folder."big_thumb_".$itemData['item_image_3'] : "";
        $itemData['image_3_url'] = $itemData['item_image_3'] != "" ? $image3_Folder.$itemData['item_image_3'] : "";

        $itemData['print_mileage'] = $itemData['mileage'] == "" ? $this->lang->getText('NRS_UNLIMITED_TEXT') : $itemData['mileage']."".$this->measurementUnit;
        if($paramBasicDetails == FALSE)
        {
            $itemData['print_features_for_list'] = $this->getSelectedFeatures($itemData['item_id'], TRUE);
            $itemData['print_features'] = $this->getSelectedFeatures($itemData['item_id']);
        }

        // Show of hide fields
        $itemData['show_manufacturer'] = $itemData['manufacturer_id'] > 0 && $itemData['manufacturer_title'] != "" ? TRUE : FALSE;
        $itemData['show_model_name'] = TRUE; // Always true - this field is mandatory
        $itemData['show_body_type'] = $itemData['body_type_id'] > 0 && $itemData['body_type_title'] != "" ? TRUE : FALSE;
        $itemData['show_transmission_type'] =$itemData['transmission_type_id'] > 0 && $itemData['transmission_type_title'] != "" ? TRUE : FALSE;
        $itemData['show_fuel_type'] = $itemData['fuel_type_id'] > 0 && $itemData['fuel_type_title'] != "" ? TRUE : FALSE;
        $itemData['show_fuel_consumption'] = $itemData['fuel_consumption'] != "" ? TRUE : FALSE;
        $itemData['show_max_passengers'] = $itemData['max_passengers'] > 0 ? TRUE : FALSE;

        $itemData['show_engine_capacity'] = $itemData['engine_capacity'] != "" ? TRUE : FALSE;
        $itemData['show_max_luggage'] = $itemData['max_luggage'] > 0 ? TRUE : FALSE;
        $itemData['show_item_doors'] = $itemData['item_doors'] > 0 ? TRUE : FALSE;
        $itemData['show_min_driver_age'] = $itemData['min_driver_age'] > 0 ? TRUE : FALSE;

        $itemData['show_mileage'] = $itemData['mileage'] > 0 || $itemData['mileage'] == "" ? TRUE : FALSE;
    }

    return $itemData;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$itemData['show_min_driver_age'] = $itemData['min_driver_age'] > 0 ? TRUE : FALSE;
echo $itemData['show_min_driver_age']." Years";
```

Comment: tryied this but didn't work :                 $itemData['show_min_driver_age'] = echo $itemData['show_min_driver_age']." Years"; > 0 ? TRUE : FALSE;

Comment: do as mentioned above

Comment: Now the page load but it print outside the block : 1 Years Years Years Years Years Years Years Years Years Years Years Years Years Years

Comment: @user3206631 are u print it inside loop or please post ur complete code

Comment: Please check above :)

Comment: $itemData['min_driver_age'] contains the mininum driver age and you want to echo it if  $itemData['show_min_driver_age'] is true...is it so?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$temp = " Years";

echo $itemData['show_min_driver_age']. $temp;
```

You can use temporary variable to print anything after the driver age

Comment: tried this :  $temp = " Years";
            $itemData['show_min_driver_age'] = echo $itemData['show_min_driver_age']. $temp; > 0 ? TRUE : FALSE;  but it print 18 years years years years outside the block

Comment: try this --$temp = " Years";
$itemData['show_min_driver_age'] = $itemData['min_driver_age'] > 0 ? TRUE : FALSE;
if($itemData['show_min_driver_age']){
echo $itemData['show_min_driver_age'].$temp;
}

Comment: printed it outside the block " 1 years " / Please can you check my original post, i have edited it with the complete code ! maybe i forget to mention something that make your code not working! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As your If condition try this

```
$itemData['show_min_driver_age'] = $itemData['min_driver_age'] >= 18 ? $itemData['min_driver_age'].' Years': FALSE;
echo  $itemData['show_min_driver_age'];
```

Comment: Tried it , the page load but no "years" printed after the age